# 2D FFT of a image using c# aforge.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-processing, neural-network, aforge

Is it's possible to get 2d-fft of image using aforge.net 
i want get numeric values form original image to distinct image from other image

note :
i doing seed identification project after capture seed image detect the seed shape and
edge pattern(using some image processing function )after that i need get 2d-fft of each seed image ( those are black and white image ) and store to the database

I did rest of the part using aforge.net but some people say using Mathlab can do this task easy but Mathlab not free people here any idea ?

I have no much knowledge about mathematics and neural network just school boy I hard from some one you can get 2d-fft of image that's way I'm stuck with this thing

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the [ComplexImage](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/8ec218c8-628b-e6b9-c398-3d65f14280d5.htm) class in AForge.NET contains [methods](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f41aa9cf-a0ed-ef1b-a966-2e86a9954f4b.htm) for doing both forward and backward Fourier transforms.